# Update two xml nodes with the same name using powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, scripting

I am trying to update the value of two nodes with the same name. Can someone please help as I'm new to PowerShell scripting. I have applied the loop for Recipient, since there are multiple Recipients in the xml.
First loop is for multiple xml files in the folder.
Second loop is for multiple recipients in the xml file.

My code

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\sneha\Desktop\Test *.xml | 
    % { 

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $_)

$element =  $xml.SelectNodes("//Document//Recipient")
foreach ($elements in $element)
{
$elements.RecipientId='SIT12345'
$elements.RecipientName='SITXYZ'
$elements.RecipientAddress1='SITAddress 1'
$elements.RecipientAddress2='SITAddress 2'
$elements.RecipientAddress3='SITAddress 3'
$elements.RecipientFaxNumber='12345678'
$elements.RecipientZipcode='sit'
$elements.RecipientEmail='sit@abc.com'
}
$xml.Save($_)
    }
```

Actual XML

```
  <Document>
    <Recipient>
      <RecipientType>RELATED PARTY COPY</RecipientType>
      <RecipientId>SIT12345</RecipientId>
      <RecipientName>SITXYZ</RecipientName>
      <RecipientAddress1>SITAddress 1</RecipientAddress1>
      <RecipientAddress2>SITAddress 2</RecipientAddress2>
      <RecipientAddress3>SITAddress 3</RecipientAddress3>
      <RecipientAddress4>
      </RecipientAddress4>
      <RecipientZipcode>sit</RecipientZipcode>
      <RecipientCountryCode>GBR</RecipientCountryCode>
      <RecipientCountry>UNITED KINGDOM</RecipientCountry>
      <RecipientFaxNumber>12345678</RecipientFaxNumber>
**      <RecipientEmail>abc.com</RecipientEmail>
      <RecipientEmail>xyz@victor-buck.com</RecipientEmail>**
    </Recipient>
</Document>
<Document>
    <Recipient>
      <RecipientType>RELATED PARTY COPY</RecipientType>
      <RecipientId>SIT12345</RecipientId>
      <RecipientName>SITXYZ</RecipientName>
      <RecipientAddress1>SITAddress 1</RecipientAddress1>
      <RecipientAddress2>SITAddress 2</RecipientAddress2>
      <RecipientAddress3>SITAddress 3</RecipientAddress3>
      <RecipientAddress4>
      </RecipientAddress4>
      <RecipientZipcode>sit</RecipientZipcode>
      <RecipientCountryCode>GBR</RecipientCountryCode>
      <RecipientCountry>UNITED KINGDOM</RecipientCountry>
      <RecipientFaxNumber>12345678</RecipientFaxNumber>
**      <RecipientEmail>abc.com</RecipientEmail>
      <RecipientEmail>xyz@victor-buck.com</RecipientEmail>**
    </Recipient>
</Document>
```

Expected XML

```
<DocumentDelivery>
  <Document>
    <Recipient>
      <RecipientType>RELATED PARTY COPY</RecipientType>
      <RecipientId>SIT12345</RecipientId>
      <RecipientName>SITXYZ</RecipientName>
      <RecipientAddress1>SITAddress 1</RecipientAddress1>
      <RecipientAddress2>SITAddress 2</RecipientAddress2>
      <RecipientAddress3>SITAddress 3</RecipientAddress3>
      <RecipientAddress4>
      </RecipientAddress4>
      <RecipientZipcode>sit</RecipientZipcode>
      <RecipientCountryCode>GBR</RecipientCountryCode>
      <RecipientCountry>UNITED KINGDOM</RecipientCountry>
      <RecipientFaxNumber>12345678</RecipientFaxNumber>
**      <RecipientEmail>sit@abc.com</RecipientEmail>
      <RecipientEmail>sit@abc.com</RecipientEmail>**
    </Recipient>
   </Document>
<Document>
    <Recipient>
      <RecipientType>RELATED PARTY COPY</RecipientType>
      <RecipientId>SIT12345</RecipientId>
      <RecipientName>SITXYZ</RecipientName>
      <RecipientAddress1>SITAddress 1</RecipientAddress1>
      <RecipientAddress2>SITAddress 2</RecipientAddress2>
      <RecipientAddress3>SITAddress 3</RecipientAddress3>
      <RecipientAddress4>
      </RecipientAddress4>
      <RecipientZipcode>sit</RecipientZipcode>
      <RecipientCountryCode>GBR</RecipientCountryCode>
      <RecipientCountry>UNITED KINGDOM</RecipientCountry>
      <RecipientFaxNumber>12345678</RecipientFaxNumber>
**      <RecipientEmail>abc.com</RecipientEmail>
      <RecipientEmail>xyz@victor-buck.com</RecipientEmail>**
    </Recipient>
</Document>
```

I have even tried to apply loop but its not helping.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\sneha\Desktop\Test *.xml | 
    % { 

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $_)

$element =  $xml.SelectNodes("//Document//Recipient")
foreach ($elements in $element)
{
$elementCount=$elements.RecipientEmail.Count

if($elementCount -eq 1)
{
    $elements.RecipientEmail='sittest@abc.com'
}
elseif($elementCount -gt 1)
{
    
    foreach ($node in  $xml.SelectNodes("//Document//Recipient//RecipientEmail")) {
    $node ='sit@abc.com'
    }
}
}
$xml.Save($_)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use PowerShell's xml dot notation for this, but you have to be care where [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration) might come in handy with reading information:

```
$Xml.DocumentDelivery.Document.Recipient.RecipientEmail
abc.com
xyz@victor-buck.com
abc.com
xyz@victor-buck.com
```

You will need to be specific for each (`Document` and `RecipientEmail`) node if you want to write to it. This means that your first email address is not `$Xml.DocumentDelivery.Document.Recipient.RecipientEmail[0]` but actually `$Xml.DocumentDelivery.Document[0].Recipient.RecipientEmail[0]`.
Besides, there is [an issue that causes each `xml` leaf to cast to a string](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16878), which you might resolve with using the `.SelectNodes()` method.

```
$Xml.DocumentDelivery.Document.foreach{
    $Id = $_.Recipient.RecipientId
    $_.Recipient.SelectNodes('RecipientEmail').foreach{ $_.InnerText = "$Id@abc.com" }
}

$Xml.DocumentDelivery.Document.Recipient.RecipientEmail
SIT12345@abc.com
SIT12345@abc.com
SIT12345@abc.com
SIT12345@abc.com
```